# "Forgive me about it" vs "Forgive me for it"

Tags: prepositions, usage

If I suspected someone and eventually I found that it wasn't right. The I want to sorry and ask him to forgive me. Then what's of the following common in use?

> "Forgive me **about** it"

or

> "Forgive me **for** it"

Comment: Use *for* with forgive: "Forgive me for offending you."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain patterns which you should use

> forgive...for
>   Please forgive me **for** *(doing)* it.
>
> forget about
>   Let's forget **about** it *(ever happening)*.

Comment: Indeed, I think that I confused with "**forget** about it". Thank you

Comment: No problem. Fugget about it!